# Can I force numfmt to always output a number scaled to Kilo instead of the auto-scale?

Tags: coreutils

Can I make `numfmt` output the input number scaled to Kilo even when it is in another range, like in this sample Giga?

```
> LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8" numfmt --to=si --format=%.6f --suffix=Wh 20621589913 
20.621590GWh
```

Seems to me like it would be a reasonable feature but I could not find it from reading the man page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure this is what you’re looking for, but you can disable scaling, and specify units of 1000:

```
$ numfmt --to=none --to-unit=1000 --format=%.6f --suffix=kWh 20621589913
20621589.913000kWh
```

If you want to have the format calculated automatically to show the equivalent of a given unit (`%.3f` if it’s mega to kilo, `%.6g` if it’s giga to kilo etc.), I don’t think that’s possible.

Comment: Thank you :) Based on your solution, I still wanted thousand-grouping, so now I'm using: `numfmt --to=none --to-unit=1000 --format="%'.f" --suffix=kWh --round=towards-zero 2000000000`  -->  2.000.000kWh